# Graph cut with python: How to set up the graph correctly?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, graph, max-flow

I want to use the graph cut algorithm on images in my project, I'm using **python 2.7**.
I found the [pymaxflow implementation](https://github.com/pmneila/PyMaxflow), but the documentation doesn't seems so clear.
I make an example, here is my 5*5 matrix:

```
>>> A
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Virtual terminal nodes, **S** (source) and **T** (sink) should be connected with infinite weight arcs to all pixels of the leftmost and rightmost columns of the matrix respectively.
Here is what I'd like to obtain:

[image: Graph rapresentation to obtain]

Here is my code to obtain this, but it doesn't work

```
left_most = concatenate((np.zeros((1, A.shape[0])), np.arange(A.shape[0]).reshape(1, A.shape[0]))).astype(np.uint64)
left_most = np.ravel_multi_index(left_most, A.shape)
right_most = concatenate((np.ones((1, A.shape[0])) * size(A, 1) - 1, np.arange(A.shape[0]).reshape(1, A.shape[0]))).astype(np.uint64)
right_most = np.ravel_multi_index(right_most, A.shape)
g.add_grid_tedges(left_most, np.ones(left_most.shape) * np.inf, np.zeros(left_most.shape))
g.add_grid_tedges(right_most, np.zeros(right_most.shape), np.ones(right_most.shape) * np.inf)
```

`g.maxflow()` makes the python console in an infinite loop.
I'm not sure about my implementation: What is the way to make a correct graph that can be used in the graph cut algorithm?

Thanks!

P.s. If you know the solution with another library tell me, any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For working with graphs, I'd recommend the `networkx` package.  It has many features, including a max-flow function (with example):

http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.maximum_flow_value.html#networkx.algorithms.flow.maximum_flow_value